# Wordpress $_GET COOKIE

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте, работаю с wordpress впервые.
Мне нужно сделать чтобы шаблон и данные внутри него переключались по нажатию на кнопку, мол зима / лето

решил передавать get запрос и в зависимости от него устанавливать куку по которой потом смогу писать условия для вывода
передаю вот таким образом,

```
<a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url')."?weather=summer"?>">
Лето
</a>
```

в functions.php

```
function codenode_set_weather(){
    $weather = $_GET['weather'];
    switch($weather){
        case "summer": 
        case "winter": setrawcookie('weather', $weather, time()+3600 * 3); break;
        default: break;
    }
    }
add_action('init', $codenode_set_weather);
```

и мне кажется это очень топорно костыльный способ, может можно более аккуратно это сделать?
П.С И кстати почему то не работает не въехал пока почему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> и мне кажется это очень топорно костыльный способ, может можно более аккуратно это сделать?

Добро пожаловать в вордпресс. Насколько знаю, там нет дополнительных удобных функцию для работы с куки, да и сама логика слишком проста, здесь все нормально, кроме самого свитча:

```
if (isset($_GET['weather']) && in_array($_GET['weather'], array('summer', 'winter')) {
    setcookie('weather', $_GET['weather'], time() + (3600 * 3));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за ваш ответ, а что на ваш взгляд плохо в свитче?

Comment: @0xdef, он и логически здесь неприменим, и операцию выполняет довольно странную для свитча. Функционал тот же.

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы уточнить: администратор меняет данные или пользователь, нажатием кнопки?)

На данный момент я себе вижу реализацию данной задачи использованием двух шаблонов.
Куда удобнее дать пользователю выбор шаблона, чем заново изобретать велосипед.

Comment: Пользователь меняет нажатием кнопки, 
изменяется фоновое изображение, слайдшоу, галерея. очень много дубля кода будет если дублировать весь шаблон
Куда посмотреть чтобы разобраться в "дать пользователю выбор из 2 шаблонов"

Comment: http://www.sooource.net/wordpress-theme-switcher
это первый вариант который я нашел в google
Просто при использовании 2-х тем у вас отпадает необходимость в дополнительных костыльных функциях.
я за простоту и изящность...